# Linear regression line on facet grid with logarithmic Y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have code working exactly as I want: it plots two colored datasets, `TypeA` and `TypeB`, on three plots separated by the value `Divison` with a logarithmic axis for Y only.

```
pal = dict(TypeA="seagreen", TypeB="gray")
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, hue="Source", col='Division', palette=pal, size=5)
g.map(plt.scatter, "X_Data", "Y_LogData")
g.add_legend();
g.set(yscale="log")
```

[image: Facet Plot]

How can I get a linear regression line to plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib's [`plt.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) does not calculate a regression line. Pass [`sns.regplot`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) to `g.map()` instead, which calculates a regression line by default.

You can see some examples [here](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/axis_grids.html) where different plotting functions are used with `FacetGrid.map()` (which is `g.map()` in your code).